# Does filename represent a directory

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I have the procedure below. It is meant to check if a filename represents a directory or not, setting the Carry flag if it is a directory, clearing it otherwise.

Right now it works with the files and directories I have tested it against, but I suspect this is a mere coincidence, because I couldn't find any useful documentation on the stat() function so I had to make guesses.

What I need to know is at which offset in the structure I can find whether the file is a directory or not, and which value means what. From my testing I found that all my test files had a value of 1 at offset 20 while directories had either 2 or 3, but that's likely just a coincidence, I have no clue what the value at offset 20 actually represents. Could be anything, or nothing.

Also, I set aside 100 bytes for the structure, but I suspect that's probably way too much memory. Again, I could really use some documentation for this which relates to assembly rather than C. Everything out there is about C, and the best I can do with that is to make guesses.

```
...

[SECTION .bss]
StatBuf     resb 100

...

isdir:
    pushad

    push StatBuf
    push eax                ; Filename passed in eax
    call stat
    add esp, 8

    cmp eax, 0              ; stat returns 0 on success
    jne .error              ; -1 (not 0) on failure

    mov eax, StatBuf    ; Stats stored in StatBuf

    cmp byte [eax+20], 1    ; Guess: All files have value 1 at offset 20?
    jne .yes                ; Guess: Dirs either 2 or 3?

    clc                     ; Not a directory
    jmp .done

    .yes:
        stc                 ; File is a directory
        jmp .done

    .error:
        clc                 ; Error, not a directory
        jmp .done

    .done:
        popad
        ret
```

**update 0**
I now do the following, and again it appears to work but I'm unsure if it is actually correct. The value in `ebx` after the `and` appears to be 0 for files and 64 for directories, shouldn't it be the other way around (0 for directories)?

```
mov eax, StatBuf

mov ebx, dword [eax+17]
and ebx, 0x40

cmp ebx, 0
jne .yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check for  [`S_IFDIR` in the `st_mode` member](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat). That's the third member, and should be a single bit value (it's defined as a mask) somewhere between the `[16]`th and `[23]`rd byte. I would give more information but I'm on a Windoze box right now.

### Update0

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

main() {
    printf("st_mode offset = %zu\n", offsetof(struct stat, st_mode));
    printf("S_IFDIR mask = %x\n", S_IFDIR);
}
```

Executing gives me:

```
matt@stanley:~$ gcc -o mask /home/matt/Desktop/mask.c
matt@stanley:~$ ./mask 
st_mode offset = 24
S_IFDIR mask = 4000
```

Since the machine is little endian, this tells us that it's a directory if the 25th byte's 2nd most significant bit is set. In assembly you should read this byte `[eax+25]`, `and` it with `0x40`, and then compare to zero.

Or you could learn C.

### Update1

The above was performed on a x86_64 OS. The location will be different on x86.

### Update2

The value of `ebx` after `and ebx 0x40` will be non-zero if it's a directory.

Again if you used C, you wouldn't need to worry what your platform is. However if you compile your program for a 32 bit OS, it will still run correctly under a 64 bit OS if that OS supports 32 bit binaries. I would take this route if you're doing it in assembly.

Comment: How do I access S_IFDIR, or alternately what is its actual value? And what should I be looking for to identify the right byte? I'm fairly new to this and feel like I'm walking blindly at lot of the time when it comes to the C library.

Comment: +1. @MCXXII: One reason that the documentation is all C-oriented is that the answer will vary from machine to machine. The C compiler abstracts this all away, by providing appropriate definitions in the system headers. The simplest way to get system-specific information is to ask the C compiler, by writing a short program such as Matt Joiner writes in his "Update0". As for the actual value of `S_IFDIR` -- that's specified in the man-page, http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html, to be 0040000, i.e. 16,384, i.e. 0x4000.

Comment: Hmm, I get an offset of 17. If the offset varies even between two linux machines, then it's pretty much useless, isn't it? I now do as you suggest, except I read `[eax+17]`, and it seems to work, but I still don't feel confident about the code actually doing what I think it does. I know C, but so far that seems to help only little in assembly. I'm only doing this in assembly as a way to learn the language, I know it would be a lot more practical in C or some other high-level language, but that's not the point.

Comment: @MCXXIII: My bad, I did this on x64. Your byte location is probably correct, running my C program will still give this to you correctly.

Comment: @MattJoiner I added my corrections to the question, just wanted to make sure if I've got it right or not. As long as the offset is correct on 32 bit Linux it should be OK, though is there a way to determine if the system is 32 or 64 bits so the correct value can be used on both?

Comment: So it is correct. Just wanted to be certain. Thank you for your help.